# how to prevent newly created elements by javascript to disappear when is refreshed?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Actually i am making list ... first i get the user info and store it into mysql database . when user clicks 'add' button a new element of list appears in the bottom of list as the part of list which is already coded in html. Now the problem is when i refresh the page the the new created element of list disappears ? Any suggestions?

```
<html>
                  <ul id="list" class="list-group" style="margin-top:20vh ;opacity:0.3;">
                        <a href="#"  class="list-group-item list-group-item-action active" id="myBtn"><span class="badge badge-primary badge-pill">+</span>Add shop</a>

                        <a href="#" onclick="location.href='action.php';" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" id="bg" >Emporium</a>
                    </ul>
  </html>  
<script>
function newuser() {
        var ul = document.getElementById("list");
        var li = document.createElement("a");
        li.appendChild(document.createTextNode("<?php echo $row3['shopname'] ?>"));

        li.setAttribute("id", "bg"); // added line
        li.setAttribute("class", "list-group-item list-group-item-action");
        li.setAttribute("href", "#");
        //    li.insertBefore(li, ul.children[0]);
        ul.appendChild(li);

    }
</script>
```

Comment: You have to show the code you use to display the existing data

Comment: can anyone modify my code? i can give more code relevent to it ...if  needed

Answer (score 1):

When you will reload the page, JS files will reload and execute again, so if you want some action based on some event and store that action event after reload, use cookie, local storage, or session storage and store some flag, based on that trigger your function on page load.

Comment: can u please guide me furhter about it?

Answer (score 1):

The page is rendered again every time you refresh the page. The JavaScript block will be executed again too. So nothing you create will 'inject' into your file with the code or stay there forever.

However, there are solutions that can help you achieve that (or simulate it). For example, [localStorage](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_localstorage.asp) or [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage). Personally, I'd use localStorage for that purpose (unless there's some sensitive data included, e.g. bank account info and similar stuff). On page load where you'd have your form shown, you immediately invoke a method for getting an existing data object inside `localStorage`, e.g. `localStorage.getItem(data)`. The localStorage and sessionStorage properties allow to save key/value pairs in a web browser. The localStorage object stores data with no expiration date. The data will not be deleted when the browser is closed, and will be available the next day, week, or year.

For example, if you want to keep the elements in a todo list, you might want to do something like this:

```js
const addButton = document.querySelector("#addToDo");
const delBtn = document.querySelector("#delToDo");

addButton.addEventListener("click", addTask, false);
var tasksID = 0;

function saveTask(taskID, taskInfo) {
  // Get tasks from local storage
  let tasks = localStorage.getItem("todo-tasks");

  if (!tasks) {
    tasks = {};
  } else {
    tasks = JSON.parse(tasks);
    tasks[taskID] = taskInfo;
  }

  // Save the result back
  let infobj = JSON.stringify(tasks);
  localStorage.setItem("todo-tasks", infobj);
}

function drawSavedTasks() {
  let tasks = localStorage.getItem("todo-tasks");
  if (tasks) {
    tasks = JSON.parse(tasks);
    Object.keys(tasks).forEach(k => {
      addTask(null, tasks[k]);
    });
  }
}

drawSavedTasks();

function addTask(e, textToDo = undefined) {
  if (!textToDo) {
    textToDo = document.querySelector("#toDo").value;
  }

  var list = document.querySelector(".list");
  var divToDo = document.createElement("div");
  var p = document.createElement("p");
  var delButton = document.createElement("button");

  divToDo.setAttribute("id", "todo" + tasksID);
  divToDo.setAttribute("class", "toDo");
  delButton.classList.add("delToDo");

  delButton.textContent = "Delete";
  p.textContent = textToDo;

  delButton.onclick = function() {
    divToDo.parentNode.removeChild(divToDo);
  }

  divToDo.appendChild(p);
  divToDo.appendChild(delButton);

  list.appendChild(divToDo);
  saveTask(tasksID, textToDo);
  ++tasksID;
}
```

```css
.toDo {
  width: 200px;
  height: 80px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="form">
  <input type="text" id="toDo" placeholder="To do...">
  <button id="addToDo">Add</button>
</div>

<div class="list">

</div>
```

**Note: The jsfiddle is not broken!** *Since JSFiddle loads the code under an iframe, you must select it on your developer console before running the code for the localStorage to work, or you might test it locally. If the HTML can not be seen, press the Full-page button.* (Info [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jfo0V.png)).

Note the functions `saveTask` and `drawSavedTasks`. `drawSavedTasks` is called first so anything you saved do be redrawn. Also, I don't save the entire previously created object, but only some relevant info about it, so I can re-create it.

Another solution would be if you'd use a database and/or a framework. Here, in the same way as with `localStorage`, you can save some metadata about the objects and redraw them on reload easily. For example, angularjs has a directive called `ng-repeat` where for every item in an array, a new element will be created when the page will be rendered. This can also be done with react or even laravel if you use php.

```
@foreach($itemas $itemsList)
    <div>
        Some data
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Hope this helped you.
Cheers!